# Grunt: Unable to access jarfile node_modules/protractor/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar

Tags: selenium, gruntjs, protractor

I am new to Grunt and I am having trouble when using it.
Receive the following error when I use the grunt command:

jasmine_node task

> > Error: Unable to access jarfile node_modules/protractor/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar

I was suspecting that Protractor was outdated, but updated it and had no problem.

Has anyone else come across the same problem?

both selenium and webdriver are up to date

Answer (score 3):

I believe you have to run `webdriver-manager update` first, to download selenium server. 
`node_modules\.bin\webdriver-manager update` if you don`t have it globally.